# How to cause overflow of the neighbor cell when using negative margin

Tags: css, html

I want to use negative margins to cause overflow on a neighbor table-cell when using CSS table layout.

Update 3 - here's what I want but without green box width specified explicitly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="display: table; margin-left: 300px;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">

            <!--Hack: width: 250px;-->
            <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: green; height: 30px; overflow-x: visible; width: 250px;"></div>


            <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: gray; height: 30px;">

                <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: azure;">
                    <div style="position: relative; width: 500px; margin-left: -250px; background-color: yellow; height: 5px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update 2

@Per Salbark - the case is rather simple. The yellow box is styled by the user while the grin & gray ones are the 'framework' part. Yellow box's center must be aligned by the right edge of the first cell. Green and Gray boxes widths must be the same and be equal to Yellow box width /2. (Note I put a ? mark into the green cell just to ensure it's visible otherwise it should be blank).

The key point here is when people style their yellow box they don't need to know that the green one needs to be styled too just because of negative margins won't work.

Update 1 -

Q: Why do I need it?

A: I'm trying to keep my layout as dynamic as possible. The green cell hosts something of an unknown width, and the yellow box width is also variable. I have to display their content in full. I'd thought that the main div (table) would overflow and expand itself using the first cell, which didn't happen.

http://jsbin.com/koqefomevulu/1/edit?html,output

```
<div style="display: table; margin-left: 300px;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: green; overflow-x: visible; 
         height: 30px">
        ?
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; background-color: gray; height: 30px;">
            <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; background-color: azure;">
                <div style="position: relative; width: 500px;
                 margin-left: -250px; background-color: yellow; height: 5px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I want the green cell to expand by `250px` to fully fit the yellow box - wonder if it's possible to achieve it?

Comment: That's a tricky one for sure... might be better to explain what you are trying to achieve and look for an alternative solution

Comment: Can the HTML structure be changed?

Comment: @misterManSam It can be.

Comment: Like musefan said, can you better desribe the end result you want? Do you have a mock-up image to look at?

Comment: @Per Salbark I want the green box to fully include the yellow one. They are part of the same table at the end of the day!

Comment: Ok. Well, I can tell you right now that it won't happen with pure CSS. The green and the yellow elements have a DOM relationship that is not easy to target with CSS, and the negative margin isn't helping :)
So that makes me wonder if this is the right aproach. I asked to to see a screenshot of what you are aiming for in order to suggest a different method alltogether.
If you seriously want to solve this problem, and you can change the HTML and CSS in any way, I think I can help you. But not without seeing an example of the desired end result with correct content.

Comment: Can you put 2 screen on ur question, i don t understand your problem :p

Comment: @Per Salbark & ColoO please look at the JSBin link I've updated the question too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not getting it. Sorry. Maybe someone else will understand...

Comment: yeah same for me :/. yellow width = grey + green width ?

Comment: Guys did you try the JSBIN link???

Comment: i see the jsbin BUT i don t understand what you want. with some screen is more easy. example 1 with content, example 2 without content etc...

Comment: In JSBIN there're three boxes yellow, gray and green. The green one has '?' mark in it. The whole task is define in terms of colors, please look at the link!

Comment: Sorry but I'm with those guys above. I read your description a couple of times and looked at the jsbin, but I'm still not sure what exactly you expect to happen.

Comment: I've added the desired look achieved by specifying the width of the green box as half of the width of the yellow one. It's a hack the width of the yellow box is unknown. The layout should look the same regardless of the yellow box width and w/out specifying width for the green box. Doh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : see this: http://jsbin.com/xibeyucelowu/1/  -- don't need to set fixed margin or width with this -- better than the other fiddle I posted, I think..

---

How's this: http://jsbin.com/koqefomevulu/29/ ?

It's works similarly to the hack of setting green's width to `250px`

It works because the width of yellow is exactly twice of it's negative margin... Maybe some JS to set the negative margin once the dynamic content of yellow is loaded? You'll only need to target one element this way. I don't think you'll find a solution with just CSS..

Is it necessary to use table styling?

Comment: Not badm but what I'm not controlling yellow bar styling - that's the kye. If you remove text from the green box and set yellow box's width to 500 (which is what people will do) we are back to square one.

Comment: Removing text from green box won't change anything... So you have no control of any styles for yellow? What sort of input are you allowing user to provide? Only a pixel based width, or more settings as well?

Comment: Yellow box can have class names and also contains custom rendered content.